# Google Search Automation Script using Watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I have to run a ruby script in watir webdriver to automate google search. Then click on first link in google search results and check if my search term exists on that page. So far I am able to reach till step where I have automated searching part but I am not able to click on first link. Here is what I have so far:

```
    require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'http://google.com'
b.text_field(:name,'q').set 'santa clara university'
b.button(:name,'btnG').click
b.link(:href, 'http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd…usg=AFQjCNHi39wrFlDMd6h8oAmkVgpkA6kYeQ&bvm=bv.84607526,d.cGU').fire_event('onmousedown')
```

I am trying to click on first link using its href field mentioned under "onmousedown"  tag. Can anyone help?

Comment: I dunno if google wants you doing that.  But if you must, just use a `:text` locator.

Comment: I tried using :text locator, but it does not fetch any result.

Comment: Any interest in scripting tests with RSpec and Capybara instead?

Comment: Where is that link supposed to go to? I do not see that URL anywhere. At any rate, it is likely a timing issue due to the asynchronous loading of the page. Try using one of the wait methods such as `when_present`.

Comment: @JustinKo that link is supposed to be the link of first result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All links in google search result has h3 header with class 'r', so you can use te next statement:

```
b.h3s(:class=>'r')[0].click
```

To open the first link in the results.